# Openshift pod permission issue EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.cache'

Tags: permissions, openshift

I am trying to build a docker image and trying to deploy to OpenShift, below is the docker file

```
FROM node:14.18.0-alpine
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN chgrp -R 0 /usr/src/app && chmod -R g=u /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4308
```

Docker image build is fine, but I want to execute the following command inside the pod:

```
npm run build && PORT=4308 NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 NODE_ENV=uat node server
```

But when I am trying to do so in OpenShift pod, it is giving the following permission issue:

> EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.cache

How to ensure random user used by OpenShift pod should able to perform file or folder creation without any permission issues? I don't want use SCC privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea of using gid=0 for permissions.

Without seeing the container itself, I would hazard a guess that your "npm install" is creating new files/directories, and you need your chgrp/chmod to take place after that step, not before.

Comment: yes i tried adding those permission change commands after npm install as well, still have permission related errors

Comment: EPERM: operation not permitted, lchown '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.cache/angular-build-dl/tmp'.      i think during npm run build it is trying to perform some actions which is failing